# Ignore a line matching a pattern in ESLint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I generally think the [dot-notation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/dot-notation) is ideal, but for reasons, I want to ignore it when accessing properties of `process.env`. The documentation mentions how to turn off the rule for property names, but not for any sort of broader context, like the object of the property. I also know I can use `// eslint-disable-line dot-notation`, but that would be pretty noisy.

Is there a way to get ESLint to ignore a rule based on a regex applied to a full line?

Comment: Did you check this: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/dot-notation#allowpattern ? You can allow snake case based on a regex

Comment: @Fcmam5 I'm pretty sure that only applies to the property itself, not anything else in the statement or expression